# Beginner Grammar Question

Tags: grammar, word-order

First time poster on here, currently learning from the Japanese from Zero books.

In Chapter 13 of the book there is the sentence ‘what time are you going to the airport?’, now it’s written two different ways within the same chapter which is slightly confusing to me at my beginner level and so was just looking a short explanation if possible

The sentence is written as follows

> くうこうになんじにいきますか
>   (Kuukou ni nan ji ni ikimasu ka)

And it’s also written as

> なんじにくうこうにいきますか
>   (Nanji ni kuukou ni ikimasu ka)

Comment: Word order isn't so rigid in Japanese because the particles mark the function of the words. Your two sentences are basically the same. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57222/7944

Comment: Word order is so different / unnatural (not so important) in Japanese that placing yourself last in a list of people sounds neither good nor bad. I was taught English speakers always place themselves last in a list to humble themselve?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36610/is-there-a-convention-to-always-place-yourself-last-in-a-list-of-people

Answer (score 0):

so in :

> 空港に何時に行きますか

and

> 何時に空港に行きますか

their difference is  "くうこうに " which at the first sentence, it came at the beginning but at the second one it came after なんじに

they don't have much difference...the only thing that differs is the position of に !

I think the に thing confused you, there are two に in the sentence, the first one is for 時, you some times need to use 時に and other times 時 alone !!!
you can search [What is the difference between 時に and 時は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29687/what-is-the-difference-between-%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB-and-%E6%99%82%E3%81%AF)

and the other に which was used here is for sticking sentences !!! here it means "to"

hope it helps you ♥